# Android Studio Proguard fail to run

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard

In my `proguard-project.txt` file I have this line:

```
-injars      libs
```

When i try to create Signed APK i get this error:

```
Unexpected input type. Only archive types are supported, e.g., .jar, .zip, etc.
```

Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue but after removing -injars libs  -outjars bin/classes-processed.jar
from proguard-rule.pro its wokring fine.
But still i am trying to understand the reason.

For your reference: https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/utils/AndroidApp.java

Answer (score 0):

OK. After some researching, I found out that downgrade Android Studio from 3.5 to 3.3 fixes my problem.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

If we are  using Gradle plugin 3.4.0*, R8 is the default compiler its the combination of proguard  and D8 compiler, so **3.4.0* is better for build process.**

As i understand if we use R8 it will generate some progaurd rules automatically and its will not support few lines in progaurd file like injars,outjars etc... 
That's why its throwing exception like

> Unexpected input type. Only archive types are supported, e.g., .jar, .zip, etc.